# Records are not being saved in mysql DB

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, jdbc

I'm working on logIn and singUp desktop app and I have problem with mySQL.
Records are not saving in my table.
Here is my code:

```
Connection dbConnection;
public Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, 
SQLException
{
    String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://" + dbHost + ":"
            + dbPort + "/"
            + dbName;

    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

    dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString +  "?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC", dbUser, dbPass);


    return dbConnection;
}
public void signUpSave(User user)
{
    String insert = "INSERT INTO " + ConstData.LOGIN_TABLE + " (" + 
ConstData.USER_NAME + "," + ConstData.USER_SURNAME + ","
            +  ConstData.USER_LOGIN + "," + ConstData.USER_PASSWORD + ","
            + ConstData.USER_EMAIL + ") " + "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
    try{
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = 
getConnection().prepareStatement(insert);

        preparedStatement.setString(1,user.getUserName());
        preparedStatement.setString(2,user.getUserSurname());
        preparedStatement.setString(3,user.getUserLogin());
        preparedStatement.setString(4,user.getUserPassword());
        preparedStatement.setString(5,user.getUserEmail());



    } catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Those are strings that I use in above code

```
protected String dbHost = "localhost";
protected String dbPort = "3306";
protected String dbUser = "root";
protected String dbPass = "root";
protected String dbName = "login";
```

There is a method that gets all strings from textFields

```
private void createUser()
{
    DataBase dataBase = new DataBase();

    String name = nameField.getText();
    String lastName = surField.getText();
    String userLogin = logField.getText();
    String userPswd = pswField.getText();
    String userMail = mailField.getText();

    User user = new User(name, lastName, userLogin, userPswd, userMail);

    dataBase.signUpSave(user);
}
```

User class is just a class with 5 string, contructor, 5x getter&setter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly execute the prepared statement against the underlying database. For example:

```
  final int updatedRowCount = preparedStatement.executeUpdate(); // execute the update
  System.out.println("Updated rows: " + updatedRowCount);
```

- See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()